# Border gradient of input tag? And how to disable autocomplete?

Tags: html, css, border, linear-gradients

i'm trying to do a "to do list". But encountered this problem. (in fact there's two).

1. My input box isn't having the border gradient even though its correct.
   I would really like to have the linear gradient all around the text
   field. Not just the corners.
2. While the input box its focused, it has a list of the things that typed before(autocomplete).

So here's my code:

```js
function toElement() {
  var z = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if (z == "") {
    return
  }
  var x = document.createTextNode(z)
  var y = document.createElement("li");
  y.appendChild(x);
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(y);
  document.getElementById("input").value = '';
  var a = document.getElementById("input")
  a.style.width = 270 + 'px';
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap');
body {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(174, 174, 174, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(174, 174, 174, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(174, 174, 174, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#aeaeae", GradientType=1);
  user-select: none;
}

#title {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#input {
  min-width: 270px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
}

#input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #0cebeb, #20e3b2, #29ffc6);
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<p id="title" title="To do list">To Do List</p>
<div class="container">
  <form action="javascript:toElement()">
    <input type="text" id="input" oninput="this.style.width = 0; this.style.width = this.scrollWidth + 'px'" placeholder="Enter an activity...">
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Add</button>
  </form>

</div>

<ul id="list">
  <li id="obj_1">Test 1</li>
  <li id="obj_2">Test 2</li>
  <li id="obj_3">Test 3</li>
  <li id="obj_4">Test 4</li>
  <li id="obj_5">Test 5</li>
</ul>
```

I would so be thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: The linear gradient is there but tiny (2px - look at the corners, and try zooming in). What effect are you looking for?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @AHaworth I want the linear gradient to completely surround the input field

Answer (score 0):

```
border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #0cebeb, #20e3b2, #29ffc6) 1;
```

This should do it.

To disable the autocompletion, you can add `autocomplete="off"` to the form-tag.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp